# Laravel Form update multiple records

Tags: forms, laravel

I have a list of users, and for each user of the list there is a select box where the selected value role value is shown.

I was thinking a way on how allow to send all the modifications for each user with the submit button to a method of the controller which should update the role. I have no idea.

This is the form, which works correctly:

```
{!!Form::open(['url' => ['admin/users/edit'], 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

@foreach($users as $user)
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="list-user-element">{!! $user->name !!}</div>
        <div class="list-user-email">{!! $user->email !!}</div>
        <div>
            {!! Form::select('role', $roles, $user->role->label, ['class' => 'form-control']); !!}
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach

<div class="form-group">        
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5"> 
        {!! Form::submit('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) !!}
    </div>
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I don't know how to prepare the controller, neither which kind of info is passed to the controller.

```
Route::post('admin/users/edit', 'AdminController@showRegisteredUsersRoles');
```

And here it gives error:

```
public function editRegisteredUsersRoles(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

Comment: Also, Re-check your routes

Answer (score 1):

You could do the form like this

```
{!! Form::select('users[' . $user->id . '].role', $roles, $user->role->label, ['class' => 'form-control']); !!}
```

And then in the controller

```
public function editRegisteredUsersRoles(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->users as $user_id => $role) {
       //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what your problem is, are you saying that there aren't all of the users' roles in the Request when you `dd($request)` ?

I think the problem lies in the fact that you are looping through the users throwing down select boxes with the *same* name. Generally, when you send a POST request, you access the information by saying `$_POST[<Form's name>]`, so maybe there is a problem with duplication here. Perhaps you should try something like:

`{!! Form::select('role' . $user->id, $roles, $user->role->label, ['class' => 'form-control']); !!}`

What I changed above is simply tacking on the user's id to the name 'role' in order to make each of those unique.